# Como funcionam estes símbolos (text fragments) na URL "#:~:text="?

Tags: html, css

Vejo que alguns sites usam estes símbolos `#:~:text=` nos links como uma forma de destacar o texto ou uma determinada parte do texto do site no qual possui relevância.

Como, por exemplo, abaixo é aberto uma página do MDN e é colorido o plano de fundo do título "JavaScript" para amarelo:

```html
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript#:~:text=JavaScript">Click</a>
```

Só que eu não encontrei nenhuma referência explicando melhor sobre esse recurso, então surgiu algumas dúvidas minhas como:

- Existe algum termo para expressar melhor esses símbolos?
- Como mudar o `background` do texto (sem ser amarelo)?
- Por que esse recurso não funciona quando o atributo `target` com o valor `_blank` está incluso na âncora?
- Ele muda o `background` ou o `selection` da página?
- Se existe esse recurso, é possível estilizar o texto com outros estilos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é um recurso recente (possível a partir do Chrome 81, por exemplo) que permite criar um link que também determina uma posição em um determinado texto presente na página, que será destacado. É uma nova parte do URL (além da *query string*, *hash*, etc) que se chama ***[text fragment](https://web.dev/text-fragments/#text-fragments)***.

O *text fragment* é, basicamente, uma forma para se especificar um texto em um URL. Assim, quando o usuário utilizar um link que o contém, o texto será destacado, chamando a atenção do utilizador.

A forma mais simples é esta (que deve ser colocada no final do URL):

```
#:~:text=textStart
```

De modo que `textStart` esteja codificado em no formato *URL encoded*.

Você também pode especificar o fim do destacamento de modo explícito, assim:

```
#:~:text=textStart,textEnd
```

A sintaxe também te permite configurar prefixos, infixos e sufixos. Para saber mais, veja [aqui](https://web.dev/text-fragments/#the-full-syntax).

Sendo `textStart` e `textEnd` codificados em *URL encoded*.

> Porque esee recurso não funciona quando o atributo `target` com o valor `_blank` está incluso?

Não é que não funciona com o atributo `target` `_blank`. Só que para isso você deve deixar explícito que o link é, também, do tipo `noopener`. Por questões de segurança, *text fragments* só funcionam em links de caráter `noopener`. Veja:

```html
<a
  href="https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript#:~:text=JavaScript"
  target="_blank"
  rel="noopener"
>Click</a>
```

Links normais (cujo `target` é `_self` implicitamente) já são `noopener` por padrão, por isso não é necessário explicitar o `rel="noopener"` em todos os casos.

> Ele muda o `background` ou o `selection` da página?

Creio que não, até porque não deve existir um `selection` na página no momento que o *text fragment* está aparecendo (já que para isso o usuário deve ter acabado de entrar na página). Uma vez que o usuário clica no *text fragment*, ele é removido.

> Se existe este recurso é possível estilizar o texto com outros estilos?

Eu não consegui encontrar nenhum meio para customizar um *text fragment*, mas creio que isso se deve a pequena maturidade desse recurso (que ainda é muito novo e não foi sequer implementado em todos os browsers). Provavelmente no futuro será possível estilizá-los com um pseudo seletor.

---

Deixo aqui [este link](https://web.dev/text-fragments/), para entender toda a motivação e sintaxe desse novo recurso.

É importante salientar que o [suporte entre navegadores ainda é risível](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment), uma vez que, no momento que escrevo, apenas *browsers* baseados em Chromium implementaram esse recurso. Não obstante, é algo interessante e que pode ser utilizado (já que não tende a quebrar a validade de um URL).

Comment: Muito boa resposta :)